# Reorder HTML list item elements by class name in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

In the following HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item pr1">....</li>
  <li class="item pr0">....</li>
  <li class="item pr4">....</li>
  <li class="item pr3">....</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create a function that reorders the `<li>` to get a result like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item pr0">....</li>
  <li class="item pr1">....</li>
  <li class="item pr2">....</li>
  <li class="item pr3">....</li>
</ul>
```

Is this possible without having to iterate through all items?

Comment: *"Is this possible without having to iterate through all items"* - I don't think so. Whatever function you use will atleast iterate internally. This is not magic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var order = $('li.item').sort(function(a,b) {
    var classA = $(a).attr('class').replace(/^.*(pr\d).*$/, '$1');
    var classB = $(b).attr('class').replace(/^.*(pr\d).*$/, '$1');
    return classB < classA;
  });
  $('ul.list').append( order );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
<li class="item pr1">1....</li>
<li class="item pr0">0....</li>
<li class="item pr4">4....</li>
<li class="item pr3">3....</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes are commonly used to group elements together, not to uniquely identify them... If you can use  an `id` or a `data-` attribute `1,2,3` etc to make our life easier, you can simply do:

```js
$(":input").click(function() {
  $("ul li").sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("no") - $(b).data("no");
  }).appendTo("ul");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" data-no="1">..1..</li>
  <li class="item" data-no="0">..0..</li>
  <li class="item" data-no="4">..4..</li>
  <li class="item" data-no="3">..3..</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="sort" />
```

---

Sadly if you must use classnames as shown in your current setup, you can do something like:

```js
$(":input").click(function() {
  $("ul li").sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.className.split("pr")[1]) - parseInt(b.className.split("pr")[1]);
  }).appendTo("ul");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item pr1">..1..</li>
  <li class="item pr0">..0..</li>
  <li class="item pr4">..4..</li>
  <li class="item pr3">..3..</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="sort" />
```

<sub>But this will break if new classes are added later.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment it won't be possible without iterating through all the items, but using jquery and the built-in `sort` method you can do this:

```
var $lis = $('.list').children('li');

$lis.sort(function(l1, l2) {
    return $(l1).attr('class').localeCompare($(l2).attr('class'));
});

$lis.detach().appendTo($('.list'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code using detach and a single appendTo like this:

```js
$(".list > li").detach().sort(function(a, b) {
     return +$(a).attr("class").replace("item pr","") 
     - $(b).attr("class").replace("item pr","");
     }).appendTo("ul.list");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
<li class="item pr1">pr1</li>
<li class="item pr0">pr0</li>
<li class="item pr4">pr4</li>
<li class="item pr3">pr3</li>
</ul>
```

More about detach(): https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_detach.asp